# SSPR - Access PWM from my SOAP API

Tags: java, soap, passwords, ldap

PWM (Password Management) : https://code.google.com/p/pwm/

I've downloaded war file from the above link and its running on my local tomcat server.
I've a Java SOAP API which create a user directly in E-directory. Now we want to change the logic of this API. We want the API will just send all user attribute and value to PWM and PWM will create user on Edirectory.

I'm new to PWM, so I don't know how I can access PWM application from my SOAP API and pass those value to PWM. Can anyone please guide on that matter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSPR is a supported product from NETIQ. If you have SSPR, you should open a support request.

If you are using the OpenSource PWM, You will do much better to ask this in the Google Groups "pwm-general" group.
The developers of the product are active along with many experienced users.
-jim